Github Actions: Pass Arg from CI > Docker Compose > Dockerfile | ERROR: failed to solve: : invalid reference format
First time working with Github Actions to build my CI/CD. I'm trying to set an arg for a dynamically generated hash ID for my builds.
main.yml
      - name: Set commit hash
        run: echo "COMMIT_HASH=$(git rev-parse --short HEAD)" >> $GITHUB_ENV

## OTHER BUILDS FOR backend AND frontend

      - name: Build and Push Nginx Docker image
        run: |
          echo "COMMIT_HASH=${COMMIT_HASH}"
          docker build --build-arg COMMIT_HASH=${{ env.COMMIT_HASH }} -t ***/react_django_nginx:${{ env.COMMIT_HASH }} ./nginx
          docker push ***/react_django_nginx:${{ env.COMMIT_HASH }}

docker-compose.yml
services:
  backend:
    image: ***/react_django_backend:${COMMIT_HASH}
    build: ./backend

  frontend:
    image: ***/react_django_frontend:${COMMIT_HASH}
    build: ./frontend

  nginx:
    image: ***/react_django_nginx:${COMMIT_HASH}
    build: ./nginx
    args:
      - COMMIT_HASH=${COMMIT_HASH}

nginx/Dockerfile
# Use the official Nginx image from Docker Hub
ARG COMMIT_HASH
FROM nginx:1.19-alpine

ARG COMMIT_HASH
ENV COMMIT_HASH=${COMMIT_HASH}
# Debug the commit hash
RUN echo "Commit hash is: ${COMMIT_HASH}"

# Remove default nginx static assets
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*

# Copy custom configuration file from the current directory
COPY ./nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/

# Use COMMIT_HASH to reference the frontend image
COPY --from=***/react_django_frontend:${COMMIT_HASH} /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html

# Expose ports
EXPOSE 80 443

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]


Here is the output I'm getting after my Action file runs.
Run echo "COMMIT_HASH=${COMMIT_HASH}"
  echo "COMMIT_HASH=${COMMIT_HASH}"
  docker build --build-arg COMMIT_HASH=3f790b4 -t ***/react_django_nginx:3f790b4 ./nginx
  docker push ***/react_django_nginx:3f790b4
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    COMMIT_HASH: 3f790b4
COMMIT_HASH=3f790b4
#0 building with "default" instance using docker driver

#1 [internal] load .dockerignore
#1 transferring context: 845B done
#1 DONE 0.0s

#2 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
#2 transferring dockerfile: 647B done
#2 DONE 0.0s

#3 [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/nginx:1.19-alpine
#3 CANCELED
Dockerfile:17
--------------------
  15 |     
  16 |     # Use COMMIT_HASH to reference the frontend image
  17 | >>> COPY --from=***/react_django_frontend:${COMMIT_HASH} /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
  18 |     
  19 |     # Expose ports
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to parse stage name "***/react_django_frontend:${COMMIT_HASH}": invalid reference format

Based on the output, I can see that the hash ID is being generated, however, it fails to reach the command at the Dockerfile COPY --from=***/react_django_frontend:${COMMIT_HASH} /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html.
I added the ARG twice as I saw another post with a similar issue to mine, however, that didn't work either.
The goal is to have Dockerfile build my nginx based on what is able to pull for my frontend build I did previously, using the value for passed on via the arg.

Looks like ARGs are not supported there. Try using your desired source image as a separate build stage so you can COPY --from=frontend. Alternatively just replace the commit hash in your dockerfile with sed first.

Using sed worked, thank you.
